# Paint.breakText() counts glyphs, not characters

Tags: android, ligature

One of our developers ran into an issue where `Paint.breakText()` (which *says* it counts "chars") is actually counting glyphs.

Imagine that you are wrapping just the one word `"fit"`. It will fit on the line, so you expect `breakText()` to return 3. On some devices, it does; on others, the "fi" form a ligature, and `breakText()` returns **2**. This cause you to draw

```
fi
t
```

... which is not what you want!

Is there either

1. A flag to **make** `breakText()` count Java chars, not glyphs? Or
2. A way to detect that `"fi"` will be treated as a single glyph?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120905/android-is-paint-breaktext-inaccurate

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But, you know, it's actually the opposite question: "Strings made up of 'l's and 'f's extend outside of the rectangle" instead of strings with ligatures breaking prematurely.

Comment: .. if you just want to count the characters, can't you just use String.length() ?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, Julius, but what makes you think String.length() has any relevance? Imagine you are trying to wrap a longer string, like "five floozies fixed fish muffins" - all those ligatures are going to cause similar problems, but it's a much worse example because where the miswrap occurs is going to depend on the window width.

Answer (score 2):

This seems sort of sub-optimal, but the way we're dealing with it is to use `paint.breakText("fit", true, 1000, null) == 2` as a `bugExists` flag, and then use `measureText()` to check the results.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it well here: [Android: is Paint.breakText(...) inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120905/android-is-paint-breaktext-inaccurate)

my code is:

on onCreate:

```
paintOfText.setSubpixelText(true);
breakTextNumber = paintOfText.breakText(textToBreak, true,
    maximumSizeOfText, null);
```

on render class:

```
if (breakTextNumber < textToBreak.length()) {
    while (textToBreak.charAt(breakTextNumber) != ' ') {
        breakTextNumber--;
    }
    myCanvas.drawText(textToBreak.substring(0, breakTextNumber),
            placeToDrawX, placeToDrawY, paintOfText);
    myCanvas.drawText(
            textToBreak.substring(breakTextNumber+1),
            placeToDrawX, placeToDrawY2,, paintOfText);
    }
}
```

This is just to split text in 2 lines, cutting the string with spaces. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: setSubpixelText(true) do nothing on kitkat :(